# deserialize with kryo without dto class in classpath

Tags: java, serialization, kryo

Is it possible in kryo to serialize an object along with the data schema, or to get the schema from the data serialized in the standard way ? I Need to make sure that the client side doesn't need a class in classpath. to load it from serialized data and then use reflection to subtract its fields, or deserialize all data in Maps, Lists, primitive types etc same as JSON or XML

Answer (score 0):

Saves SampleBean as JSON string

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
      .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
      .set("spark.kryo.registrationRequired", "true")
      .registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[SampleBean], classOf[InternalRow]
        , classOf[Array[InternalRow]]
        , classOf[WriteTaskResult]
        , classOf[FileCommitProtocol.TaskCommitMessage]
        , classOf[ExecutedWriteSummary],
        classOf[BasicWriteTaskStats]))

    val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]")
      .config(conf)
      .getOrCreate

    import spark.implicits._
    val df = List(SampleBean("A", "B")).toDF()
    df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).json("src/main/resources/kryoTest")
    df.printSchema()
```

reads the data simple JSON

```
val sparkNew = Constant.getSparkSess
    val dfNew = sparkNew.read.json("src/main/resources/serialisedJavaObj.json").toDF()
    dfNew.printSchema()
```